# How to measure latency and udp-jitter from the end-server

Tags: cisco, udp, latency

Is there anyway to monitor a latency and jitter from SLA Router to EndClient(Linux Server).

I have tried to use IP SLA with UDP Jitter but it didn't work.

**Diagram**

```
SLA-Router ------->  Linux Server
```

Kindly Suggest me an example configuration

Thank you.

Comment: There are such applications for Linux, but product or resource recommendations are explicitly off-topic here, as they are on SE sites, except [softwarerecs.se] and [hardwarerecs.se]. Also, host configurations are off-topic here.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could run tcpdump and capture the udp packets.  Then measure the time between packets.

Comment: IP SLA is normally used to monitor service between routers.  Your diagram seems to show that the router is on the same netwoprk segment as the Linux server.  If this is the case then I don't see much point attempting to measure latency or jitter across this segment.

Comment: Sorry, above comment was supposed to be attached to the question, not your answer.